# Как на самом деле работает SecurityContextHolder в Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Если я правильно понимаю, `SecurityContextHolder` используется для хранения информации об аутентификации ТЕКУЩЕГО пользователя на сайте. Например, чтобы запомнить пользователя после входа на сайт мы можем использовать

```
Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(user);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Но, по идее, эта аутентификация должна быть видна только КОНКРЕТНОМУ ОДНОМУ потоку, который обработал запрос входа пользователя.

Если этот `SecurityContext` ассоциируется только с этим конкретным потоком, но следующий запрос на сайт обрабатывает другой поток, то почему ему *видна* эта аутентификация, если им *владеет* другой поток?

Comment: Я помню когда-то задумывался об этом, и тогда предположил следующее. У каждого пользователя есть `JSESSIONID`. Когда он входит в аккаунт, то мы связываем с этим айди его аккаунт. При следующем запросе (неважно, каким потоком он обрабатывается) мы, опять зная его `JSESSIONID`, получаем по нему его аутентифицированный акк, и кладём в `ThreadLocal`-переменную нашего контекста. И дальше в приложении оперируем уже контекстом. Повторюсь, это только предположение, я под капотом не смотрел в точности, как оно работает.

Comment: А за счёт того, что контекст хранит именно `ThreadLocal`-переменные, получается так, что потоки между собой не делят информацию о хранящихся пользователях. При этом когда мы обратимся к контексту, то получим именно текущего пользователя для текущего потока.

Comment: @Byb я тоже что-то подобное представлял, но всё не мог поставить их на свои места. Было бы понятно, если бы контекст можно было получить так 'SecurityContextHolder.getContext(JSESSIONID)', но Spring какой-то магией узнает какой именно JSESSIONID поток хочет.  Попробую ещё изучать исходники Spring Security.

Comment: @Byb нашёл ответ из Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330677/how-spring-security-get-currently-logged-in-user-in-concept). Говорится, что `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` загружает `SecurityContext` в `SecurityContextHolder` из HTTP-сессии, используя `SecurityContextRepository`

Comment: Ну да, я вот примерно и думал, что это при помощи фильтра делается. В Spring-е вообще много "магии" осуществляется как раз за счёт того, что при каждом запросе пользователя прежде всего отрабатывает куча фильтров)